# Assigning local variables to the current object of a collection render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm rendering while iterating through a collection in this manner:

```
<%= render partial: 'reply', collection: @replies %>
```

I'd like to assign locals in this render call **BUT** they would be locals pertaining to the instance of that iteration. So for instance if a reply had parent association called *post* I'd like to assign it in the same fashion as you would passing the *locals* option. Unfortunately this isn't possible to my knowledge and have to explicitly create the assignment in the partial:

**_reply.html.erb**

```
<% post = reply.post %>

<div>
  <%= post.name %>
  ...
</div>
```

Is it possible to pass locals in the initial render call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in theory it isn't possible as you want to do it, you have different options here, let it like you are right now, and inside your reply.html.erb, call for another partial with the local post.

you can even change your code for this, to make it shorter

```
<%= render @replies %>
```

and it will look for your reply partial, following name conventions. and inside that one

```
<%= render partial: 'post', locals: {post: reply.post} %>
```

if this options apply for your case.

or, don't render it like a collection but doing it with an `each`

```
<% @replies.each do |reply| %>
  <%= render reply, locals {post: reply.post} %>
<% end %>
```

you have more options, but the one you are looking for, is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. I read in an article that the `render partial: ..., collection: ...` has performance gains, which is why I started to adopt that convention. Would you happen to know if there's any any truth to this and whether the above offer something similar? Overall I'm just curious.

Comment: I am not sure if there are performance gains, but if there are some, you wouldn't render more than 100 or 1000 maybe, so it wouldn't be something remarkable... I just see that people use `render partial: ..., collection: ...` when they need to add options like layout, spacers and things like that.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again.